# How to build in a single Flutter project a build for Chrome Extension and for Browser?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome-extension, flutter-web

Flutter allows to build app for browser and for chrome extension
BUT, the structure of index.html is not the same between these 2 builds.
Is it possible to build 2 apps in a single project ?

Comment: I would like to know the same

Comment: you can follow the issue i created: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106428